# How to change label position in EPPLUS doughnut chart?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, epplus

My doughnut chart has overlapped labels and it is unreadable. How to make the labels readable by moving them? Is there a property to set? [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by enabling legend like this,

```
            var dougnutChartStyles = (ExcelPieChartSerie)doughnutSeries;
            dougnutChartStyles.DataLabel.ShowCategory = false;
```

and

```
            var excelDoughnut = worksheet.Drawings.AddChart("pieChart", eChartType.Pie3D);
            excelDoughnut.Legend.Position = eLegendPosition.Right;
```

So, labels will display as legends, not in the chart itself.